# How to disable the auto preview when pasting a file into Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When copy-paste a file from Finder to the Explorer in VS Code, the editor always auto-previews the file (even for large .csv files).

Is it possible to modify a setting to deactivate this feature?

I tried these two but they do not work.

```
"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,
"workbench.editor.enablePreviewFromQuickOpen": false,
```